# Windows Service to host WCF and also other logic

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

Want to know if it would be a good practice to host multiple WCF services inside a single Windows Service, and besides that, this same Windows Service would also perform some other logic like running periodic tasks by using Timer objects or something alike.

Is it recommended to have this all inside one Windows Service, or would you advise in splitting it up into multiple services ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on whether you view the functionality you are offering as a single unit or as possibly several units that can be used independently of each other.

If all functionality belongs together, sure, you can group it all under a single service. You can run the functionalities as their own Tasks, i.e. in their own threads. Then when the service starts, all functionality becomes available, and when the service is stopped or paused, that too happens to all functionality.

If there is no such direct link between the functionalities and/or you wish them to be startable and stoppable independently, the best choice would be IMHO to make them separate services.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say create two Windows services: one for hosting multiple WCF services and the other one for running jobs. This way, if you need to stop the second one, you won't have to take down your web services too.

By the way, I often use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) as a job scheduling framework.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Quartz.NET, looks like a viable scheduling solution